# Asp.Net MVC3 EditorFor Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This really makes no sense to me whatsoever.

I have a view model with this field in it:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Scheduled { get; set; }
```

I then display this field in the view (this is an edit view) like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Scheduled)
```

The first time after a clean/rebuild cycle, it works fine, it displays just the date in the box (I've done lots of fiddling lately to figure out a good way to have it not display the date and time in the box, and this seems the best way).

However, once I refresh the page, I get the following:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: stream
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: stream

And this error persists until another clean/rebuild cycle. The stack trace seems to indicate that the view engine is attempting to load the template from the /Shared/EditorTemplates directory. I have no template for this, since the documentation seems to indicate that it should default to a text box, which is what I want.

I'm not using a straight TextBoxFor since it doesn't do the formatting, and EditorFor seems to do that. And when I try to make a template to satisfy this exception, I'm back at the issue of trying to figure out how to format the date in the view.

So, I suppose two things will work for an answer: Why this error is happening only after the first refresh, or how to format a date inside a Razor view.

Per request, the full stack:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: stream]
>      System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) +9496369
>      System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) +232
>      System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() +86
>      System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() +160
>      System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +110
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +65
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +218
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +40
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +8945798
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +320
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +111
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +125
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) +10
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +7
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +584
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1027
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +118
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) +57
>      ASP._Page_Views_Visit_visit_Edit_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Code...\Views\Visit\Visit\Edit.cshtml:34
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
>      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>      System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19() +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7
>      System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes even less sense. In an attempt to provide further details, I fired up ProcMon, and started looking at what it was trying to access on disk, if anything. I noticed it trying to read a  __MVCSITEMAPPROVIDER under the templates folder, which didn't exist.

Knowing that I was using a slightly, erm, non-standard version of the MvcSiteMapProvider library (I upgraded it to MVC3 by hand), I decided to go get the latest version off of codeplex. Dropped it in, clean & rebuilt, and it works even after refreshes.

The problem is solved, but I still have no clue why it was only working on the first load after a clean & rebuild. According to procmon, it was still trying to access __MVCSITEMAPPROVIDER on the first load, but it worked.